# Click on button until new card is up

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

so I'm back with the question again:) I previously asked similar one but this one a bit tricky for me. so I want to make a specific card visible after clicking on next button in the carousel and stop clicking after that specific card becomes visible, here is the code I have but when executed it shows that that specific card is visible but it won't stop clicking next button. Probably my mistake is chilling but I'm learning and will get better:) thank you guys !

```
cy.get('.carouselCards').find('.1stCard').each(($el, index, $list) => {
      const cardText =  $el.find('.cardTitle').text()
        if(cardText.includes('specific name of the card I'm looking for')) {
            cy.wrap($el).should('be.visible')
        } else { cy.get ('.carouselButton').click()
            
        }
    })
```

Comment: If its so "tricky" why are you doing it now? How about make a blueprint for all the functionality you want and focus on the areas that you can acheive? Showing partial code on a logical error is pointless. You dont know where the error is hence the purpose of your question. **Pointing** us to where you think you went wrong is helpful but in this case, you dont even give a modicum of indicators on why it "doesnt work". **Show more code.**

Comment: No one wants your code. So show more of it. No one is saying hey that Vaddy code that doesnt work, I need that in my project. No one is thinking that. This is a forum to debug code. If you decide its all so secretive then you wont get help.

Comment: lol first of its no secretive lol , secondly, this is literally all the code I have , why would I send you the previous code where I literally just login to website to specifically to get to this piece of code. I know the basics, I'm literally just struggling to stop that ">(next)" button clicking, it verifies the element I'm looking for so hence I just need to understand how to write specific code to stop the button from clicking <3

Answer (score 2):

You can break the loop in Cypress by returning false. Please try below

```
    cy.get('.carouselCards').find('.1stCard').each(($el, index, $list) => {
      const cardText =  $el.find('.cardTitle').text()
        if(cardText.includes('specific name of the card I'm looking for')) {
            cy.wrap($el).should('be.visible');
            return false;
        } else { 
            cy.get ('.carouselButton').click();
        }
    })
```

Comment: hello sir! unfortunately that did not work.... I fell like that me who can't explain in the right way what exactly I want to do.... so I will try to do it better. so when my page opens up I have a carouse with 10 cards(3 of those are appeared on screen right away) then I nee to validate that every of these 10 unique cards exist or are visible, then to see the next one I need to click on next button and etc, then when the last card is validated I need to stop clicking on the button. thank you:)